# $x_0$ is a limit point of $\text{dom }f\iff f:\text{dom }f \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined in $I(x_0)-\big\{x_0\big\}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{dom}}$In the definition of the limit of a function $f:\dom f \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $x\to x_0$ I found on a book is required that $x_0$ is a limit point for $\dom f$, while in another book it is required that $f$ is defined in a neighbourood of $x_0$, besides the point $x_0$, say $I(x_0)-\big\{x_0\big\}$.

But is it true that

$x_0$ is a limit point for $\dom f$ $\iff$ $f:\dom f \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined in $I(x_0)-\big\{x_0\big\}$?

The fact that $x_0$ is a limit point guarantees that $f$ is defined at least "in the right" or "in the left" of $x_0$. I can't understand if this is enough to be able to define the limit of $f$ as $x \to x_0$.

For example considering $f(x)=\sqrt x$, is it possible to say that the limit of $f$ as $x \to 0$ is $0$? Isn't is more correct to say that the **one-sided** (right) limit of $f$ is $0$?

Moreover I'm not sure that the opposite implication holds.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advice

Comment: The two definitions are not equivalent.  I'd go with the first one except when there's some special reason to use the second. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily true that if $x_{0}$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$ in $\Bbb R$, then $f$ is defined on some neighborhood of $x_{0}$.  As a counterexample:

Suppose $f : \Bbb Q \to \Bbb R$.  Then $\sqrt{2}$ is a limit point of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, but $f$ is not defined on some neighborhood of $\sqrt{2}$.